# Living without unsigned byte in Java

Tags: java, byte

I need to write set of bytes to TCP socket:

```
byte[] b = {0x40,0x88,0xFF};
socket.getOutputStream().write( b ) ;
```

But here is no unsigned byte in Java and byte[] inicialization failes. How to write my 3 byes to socket in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Signed-ness is just a concept. Under the hood, `byte`s, signed or not, are just 8 bits. By `0xFF`, you probably mean the bits 1111 1111. What's 1111 1111 when interpreted in two's complement? -1!

So you should replace `0xFF` with `-1`.

Similarly, `0x88` is 1000 1000, or -120 in two's complement.

So you can write your byte array like so:

```
byte[] b = {0x40,-120,-1};
```

Actually, casting to `byte` does this conversion for you:

```
byte[] b = {0x40,(byte)0x88,(byte)0xFF};
```

Comment: Awesome explanation @Sweeper !! This dilemma is faced by many individuals who work on packets / frames etc (where they need to work on individual bits), many fail to realize how the bits are actually written / stored in byte when dealing with negative numbers. Yes, as he said "Signed-ness is just a concept".